# Deleting every line with a specific string in bash

Tags: bash, sed, cat

Edit:
I realized that my current code is garbage, but other ways I tried before also did not work. The problem was that I edited the files in Notepad++ on Windows, and had them running on Linux. The programm dos2unix does the trick.

Solution:
I have used Notepad++ in Windows to write my files which caused the problem. Running the files trough dos2unix fixed it.

I have written a little bash script which should delete every line of $2 which contains a word which is specified in $1 and writes the output to $3. But somehow it does not work like it should.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f          

while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do
   sed -i "/$i/d" "$2" 
done < "$1"
```

Edit:

### Example

**file 1.test:**

```
123
678
456
```

**file 2.test:**

```
dasdas123dasd
3fsef344
678 3423423
r23r23rfsad
456 dasdasd
```

running the script:

```
./script.sh 1.test 2.test
```

The output should be:

```
3fsef344
r23r23rfsad
```

but instead it is:

```
dasdas123dasd
3fsef344
678 3423423
r23r23rfsad
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "does not work like it should". An example of the two input files, the output file you get, and the output file you *want* to get would be good. See ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). BTW, you should also run your code through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) and correct what it finds.

Comment: I added an example and changed my code so that shellcheck does not detect issues.

Comment: pluse-uno for improving your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using a shell loop and sed for this?

```
$ grep -vFf file1 file2
3fsef344
r23r23rfsad
```

If that doesn't do what you need then clarify your question with a more truly representative example because "use a shell loop calling sed multiple times" is not the answer to any question. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for some of the reasons I say that.

Comment: I guess `-F` is also a good idea? OP says file1 contains words, not patterns.

Comment: Probably, depends what the OP means by a "word" of course but I added it anyway. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I could not thing of a better way to do it. The output you have written above is exactly what I want but when I execute the command it outputs dasdas123dasd too

Comment: Maybe you have white space in `1.test`? Check for that and try running `dos2unix` on your files first to see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem! I thought changing from Windows to unix in notepad++ would work but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

You're reloading `$2` and overwriting `$3` each time you call `sed`. You should apply all operations to the file instead of reloading.

```
#!/bin/bash     
set -f          

cat "$2" > "$3"
while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do
   sed -i "/$i/d" "$3"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: maybe use `cp "$2" "$3"` instead? :)